# Como validar pdf generado antes de enviar correo php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, web

Buen día, tengo problemas al validar un archivo pdf generado a partir de un formulario php, el problema que presento es:

Tengo un formulario con información que solicito para crear el pdf, al oprimir el botón de envió crea el pdf con la información y lo envía de una vez al correo, almacenado la información en una tabla mysql , necesito que me deje ver como quedo el pdf, y hay si me de la opción de enviarlo por correo y guardarla información del formulario y el pdf en una tabla mysql.
Este es el código que tengo, soy nuevo stackoverflow en español, gracias

librerías utilizadas:
PHPMailer
mpdf/mpdf.php

PHP

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  { 
function crear_pdf()
function guardar_en_base_de_datos()
function envio_email()
      }
```

formulario HTML

```
<form name="f1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Destino<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="email" id='c_email_destino' name="c_email_destino" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

Al dar en enviar ejecuta todas las funciones , necesito que solo ejecute la de crear pdf y me permita decidir si guardarla en la base de datos y enviarla al correo o descartar para que no ejecutes las demas funciones.

código PHP.

```
<?php
session
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {    
    $contador = count($_POST["pro_nombre"]);
    $ProContador=0;
    $queryValue = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$contador;$i++) {
      if(!empty($_POST["pro_nombre"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["pro_precio"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["pro_cantidad"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["pro_Descripcion"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["pro_Valor"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["pro_PDV"][$i])) {
        $ProContador++;
        if($queryValue!="") {
          $queryValue .= ",";
        }
        $queryValue .= "<tr>
    <td>" . $_POST["pro_nombre"][$i] . "</td>
    <td>" . $_POST["pro_precio"][$i] . "</td>
    <td>" . $_POST["pro_cantidad"][$i] . "</td>
    <td>" . $_POST["pro_Descripcion"][$i] . "</td>
    <td>" . $_POST["pro_Valor"][$i] . "</td>
    <td>" . $_POST["pro_PDV"][$i] . "</td>
  </tr>";

   $queryValuebs .= "(" . $_POST["pro_nombre"][$i] . "," . $_POST["pro_precio"][$i] . "," . $_POST["pro_cantidad"][$i] . "," . $_POST["pro_Descripcion"][$i] . "," . $_POST["pro_Valor"][$i] . "," . $_POST["pro_PDV"][$i] . ")";
      }
    }
    $resultado = "";
   
    $fechap = date("y-m-d",time());

    $fecha = date("ymdHis_",time());
    $file = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="attachment3/";
    $new_file_name = strtolower($fecha.$file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    $Nit=$_POST['Nit'];
    $title=$_POST['c_agente'];
    $r_legal=$_POST['Representante_Legal'];
    $dir_empresa=$_POST['Direccion_Empresa'];
    $cc_r_legal=$_POST['cc_Representante_Legal'];
    $c_email_destino=$_POST['c_email_destino'];
   
    $user=$_SESSION['alogin'];
    $reciver= 'Admin';
    $notitype='Send Feedback';
    $attachment=' ';

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {
            $attachment=$final_file;
        }
    
    $msg="  ACTA ENVIADA ";

  $env_emai="<button class='btn btn-primary' name='submit1' id='submit1' type='submit'>ENVIAR</button>";

     ob_start();
        ?>
<style type="text/css">
  .textt { font-family: "calibri"; font-weight:normal; }
  .textt2 { font-family: "calibri";}
  .textt3 { font-family: "calibri"; text-align:center; }
  </style>


<h5 class="textt3">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5>

<table style="width:100%" align='center' class="egt" border=1 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align='center'><h5 class="textt">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align='center'><h5 class="textt">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h5 class="textt">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5></td> 
  </tr> 
</table>

<br/><br/>

<table style="width:100%" align='center' class="egt" border=1 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align='center' BGCOLOR="#eaeaea"><h5 class="textt2">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5></td>    
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:100%" align='center' class="egt" border=1 cellspacing=0>

  <tr>
    <td BGCOLOR="#002A73"><h6 class="textt2" style="color:#FFFFFF">Ciudad<h6></td>
    <td BGCOLOR="#002A73"><h6 class="textt2" style="color:#FFFFFF">Dirección <h6></td>
    <td BGCOLOR="#002A73"><h6 class="textt2" style="color:#FFFFFF">Seriales <h6></td>
    <td BGCOLOR="#002A73"><h6 class="textt2" style="color:#FFFFFF">Descripción <h6></td>
    <td BGCOLOR="#002A73"><h6 class="textt2" style="color:#FFFFFF">Valor <h6></td>
    <td BGCOLOR="#002A73"><h6 class="textt2" style="color:#FFFFFF">PDV<h6></td>
  </tr>
  <?php echo $queryValue;?>
</table>
<br/>

<table style="width:100%" align='center' class="egt" border=1 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align='center'><h5 class="textt">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.
</h5></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align='center'><h5 class="textt">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h5 class="textt">TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h5></td> 
  </tr> 
</table>



<table style="width:100%" align='center' class="egt" border=0 cellspacing=0>
  
  <tr>
    <td><h6 class="textt"><br/>TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</h6></td>
    <td><h6 class="textt"><br/>TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><h6 class="textt"><br/><br/><br/></h6></td>
    <td><h6 class="textt"><br/><br/><br/></h6></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><h6 class="textt">______________________________<br/>
    FIRMA:<br/>
NOMBRE COMPLETO LEGIBLE:<br/>
TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO:<br/>
TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO:<br/>
TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO:
</h6></td>

    <td><h6 class="textt">_______________________________<br/>
FIRMA:<br/>
NOMBRE COMPLETO LEGIBLE:<br/>
TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO:<br/>
TEXTOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO:
</h6></td> 
 
</table>
      
        <?php 
        $body = ob_get_clean();

        $body = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$body);

        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
        $mpdf=new \mPDF('c','A4','','' , 30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 30);

        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;"><img src="img/telm.jpg"></div>');

        //write html to PDF
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($body);
        $dates = date("Y-m-d H-i-s");
        $file_name = "CAPTORES_ $dates.pdf";
        $envio_e = "Enviar PDF";
        //output pdf
        $content = $mpdf->Output("CAPTORES_/$file_name","F");
        
        //save to server

        $attachmentt = new Swift_Attachment($contentt,$file_name, 'application/pdf');

 $notireciver = 'Admin';
   $sqlnoti="insert into notification (notiuser,notireciver,notitype) values (:notiuser,:notireciver,:notitype)";
  $querynoti = $dbh->prepare($sqlnoti);
  $querynoti-> bindParam(':notiuser', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $querynoti-> bindParam(':notireciver', $notireciver, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $querynoti-> bindParam(':notitype', $notitype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $querynoti->execute();

  $sql="insert into feedback3 (sender, reciver, c_age, Representante, Direccion, cc_Repres, attachment, pdf, Ni, c_email_destino, Arrays) 

  values (:user,:reciver,:c_agente, :Representante, :Direccion, :cc_Repres, :attachment, :pdf, :Ni, :c_email_destino, :Arrays)";
  $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $query-> bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':reciver', $reciver, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':c_age', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':Representante', $r_legal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':Direccion', $dir_empresa, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':cc_Repres', $cc_r_legal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':Arrays', $queryValuebs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  
 
  $query-> bindParam(':Ni', $Nit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':c_email_destino', $c_email_destino, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query-> bindParam(':attachment', $attachment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute(); 
  $msg="  ACTA ENVIADA ";


 $query-> bindParam(':pdf',  $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query->execute();
  

   //librerias
  require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();

//Configuracion servidor mail
$mail->From = "correo@outlook.com"; //remitente
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //seguridad
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com"; // servidor smtp
$mail->Port = 587; //puerto
$mail->Username ='correo@outlook.com'; //nombre usuario
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx08'; //contraseña

//Agregar destinatario
$mail->AddAddress($c_email_destino);
$mail->Subject  = "Prueba de correo Sendmail";
$mail->Body  = "Hola, \nEsto es una prueba de correo.";


$contentts =("CAPTORES_/$file_name");
$mail->AddAttachment($contentts,$file_name);

//Avisar si fue enviado o no y dirigir al index
if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
           alert("Enviado Correctamente");
        </script>';
} else {
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
           alert("NO ENVIADO, intentar de nuevo");
        </script>';

        }   
        }    
?>
```

HTML

```
<form name="f1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->email); ?>">
 
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    <select name="Nombre_Agente" id='opciones' class="form-control" onchange='cambioOpciones();'>
      
            echo '<option value="'.$valores[Nombre_Agente].'">'.$valores[Nombre_Agente].'</option>';       
    </select>

    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Destino<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="email" id='c_email_destino' name="c_email_destino" class="form-control" required>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Representante<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id='Representante' type="text" name="Representante" class="form-control" required readonly>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dirección<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id='Direccion' type="text" name="Direccion" class="form-control" required readonly>
    </div>      
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
        
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">CC Repres<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id='cc_Repres' type="text" name="cc_Repres" class="form-control" required readonly>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nom<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id='c_agente' type="text" name="c_agente" class="form-control" required readonly>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ni<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input id='Ni' type="text" name="Ni" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comercial No.<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" id='Agencia_No' name="Agencia_No" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>      
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div id="productos">
<?php require_once("InputDinamico.php") ?>
</div>
<div class="btn-action float-clear">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="agregar_registros" value="Agregar Mas" onClick="AgregarMas();" />
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="borrar_registros" value="Borrar Campos" onClick="BorrarRegistro();" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">ENVIAR</button>

</div>
<div style="position: relative;">


</div>
</div>

</form>
```